# Is there a way to perform multiple 3d object recognition in unity using vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using vuforia scanner to detect and recognize a 3D object. It works well with one object but now i want to recognize multiple objects at once. I have gone through so many links but they only speak of multiple image targets and not 3d objects. If not using vuforia, is there any other sdk to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I messed with object recognition *once* but I'm pretty sure the databases are basically the "same" as 2D image target databases. That is, you can tell Vuforia to load more than one of them and they'll run simultaneously. I don't have Vuforia installed at the moment, but I know the setting is in the main script attached to the camera (you have to fiddle with it when creating your project in the first place to get it to use something other than the sample targets).

There is, however, the limit on how many *different* targets Vuforia will recognize at once (IIRC is something really small, like 2 or 3). So be aware of this when planning your project.